# from list of integers, get number closest to and less than a given value

Tags: python, list

I am writing a code in which i have to select an integer from a list which is not only closest to a given value but also less than it at the same time. How can i edit the code to meet both the conditions?

I have tried to use the in-built min() function which i have found on this site . It gives me that integer which is closest to a given value regardless of the integer being greater or smaller than given value.

```py
def price(my_list,real_price):
   closest_number=min(my_list, key=lambda x:abs(x-real_price))
   return closest_number

my_list=[101,90,70]
real_price=100
closest_number=price(my_list,real_price)
print(closest_number)
```

For the code above, I want the output to be 90 but I am getting 101

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is close; you just need to accept only numbers that are less than `real_price`:

```
def price(my_list, real_price):
   closest_number = min((number for number in my_list if number < real_price), key=lambda x: abs(x - real_price))
   return closest_number

my_list = [101,90,70]
real_price = 100
closest_number = price(my_list, real_price)
print(closest_number)
```

Output:

```
90
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `min` you should get the `max` of the numbers that are less than `real_price`:

```
def price(my_list,real_price):
    return max(price for price in my_list if price <= real_price)
```

With this change, your code would output: `90`

Comment: This will not output 90. This will output 70 as 70 has maximum difference from 100

Answer (score 0):

Using `List comprehension` and `max` you can get 90.

```
def price(my_list,real_price):
   return max([x for x in my_list if ( x <= real_price )])

my_list=[101,90,70]
real_price=100
closest_number=price(my_list,real_price)
print(closest_number)
```